# Doubts in Neural Network python code

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I have been trying to study artificial intelligence but I have following queries regarding it.

```
def sigmoid(x):
return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

# Derivative of the sigmoid function
def sigmoid_prime(x):
    return sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x))

x = np.array([0.1, 0.3])
y = 0.2
weights = np.array([-0.8, 0.5])

# The learning rate, eta in the weight step equation
learnrate = 0.5

# The neural network output
nn_output = sigmoid(x[0]*weights[0] + x[1]*weights[1])
# or nn_output = sigmoid(np.dot(x, w))

# output error
error = y - nn_output

# error gradient
error_grad = error * sigmoid_prime(np.dot(x,w))

# Gradient descent step
del_w = [ learnrate * error_grad * x[0],
          learnrate * error_grad * x[1]]
# or del_w = learnrate * error_grad * x
```

Doubts:

- Why do we multiply weights with x only, and not with y?

  ```
  nn_output = sigmoid(x[0]*weights[0] + x[1]*weights[1])
  ```
- Why do we increment the value of x while calculating gradient descent?

  ```
  del_w = [ learnrate * error_grad * x[0],
  learnrate * error_grad * x[1]]
  ```

like `x[0]` and `x[1]`

Comment: You could have a look at this and compare your code: https://seat.massey.ac.nz/personal/s.r.marsland/Code/Ch3/pcn.py

Comment: What do you mean, increment the value of `x`?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm. Analogy to the rescue!

Imagine you are aiming a cannon to a target. You have your targeting cranks (`w`) that you adjust to move the cannon (`x`) to hit the target (`y`). So you try to hit by applying crank settings (`w`) to the cannon (`x`); *you can't use the target itself (`y`) for this,* as it is not under your control. So you fire, and you hit some location from the target (`nn_output`). You see which way and how much you missed (`error`) to figure out how to change the azimuth and angle (`w`) for the next shot.

Actually, a bit more precisely, in a neural network, `x` ("input") is not really the cannon, but all the circumstances of the firing: wind speed, cannon position, cannon model and peculiarities... `w` ("weight") is not really just a crank: it's our knowledge of setting the crank depending on all of the `x` parameters ("if cannon is far from the target, make the angle higher", "if wind comes from north, adjust this way"...).

`learnrate` is how twichy you are in adjusting. Big learning rate means you adjust more quickly (nice when you're way off-target), but you risk overshooting in the other direction when finer control is needed.

One thing that might be confusing you is `x` and `y` are not coordinates, and thus are not symmetrical in their application. When you are drawing circles on screen, it makes sense to treat `x` and `y` similarly. However, here, `x` and `y` are crucially different values: `x` is actual input (e.g. `x[0]` wind speed, `x[1]` wind direction, `x[2]` cannon age, `x[3]` direction of blip on radar, `x[4]` distance to the blip on radar...), `y` is what *should* be the output (`y[0]` longitude of target, `y[1]` latitude of target) - and it makes no sense to treat them the same.